# "Featured on meta" has gone crazy

Tags: bug, status-completed

The "Featured on meta" sidebar currently shows three posts: two of which are actually featured, and the third of which ([Cast your vote for “Best of PPCG 2018”!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2018?cb=1)) ceased to be featured 40 days ago. That seems a bit too long to be just a caching problem.

Comment: I remember having the same issue with 2017's Best Of, so this might be a problem with posts that are unfeatured while locked. I've unlocked and relocked the post; it seems to have dropped of the sidebar... for now.

Comment: I've been watching this for a bit and I don't see it currently - if it reappears, let me know.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this constantly with every new feature+unfeature specifically with locked posts like Dennis said. It's been [fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369611/361699), so I'll mark this as completed instead now.