# Regarding CGCC's Best of 2019

Tags: discussion, best-of

The nominations for CGCC's best of 2019 have already been posted [here.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18672/best-of-ppcg-2019-now-accepting-nominations/18673#18673)

If it's alright, I can make another post for voting on the nominations and selecting them(I am assuming that selection is done by voting, from the [previous year's thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2018)). So if anyone wants to nominate any other noteworthy questions/answers from 2019, now is the time.

I think we should also set up another thread for 2020 since it's about to end in a few months, and it's easy to forget noteworthy answers. I can volunteer to do that as well.

Comment: We should probably do the call for categories first for 2020.

Comment: Looks like the categories have already been decided [here.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18672/best-of-ppcg-2019-now-accepting-nominations/18673#18673) Unless we want to scrap that and start over

Comment: That is for 2019 not 2020

Comment: Why 2020 before 2019?

Comment: @WheatWizard Are you starting a thread for the call of categories today?

Comment: It seems a little early I think.  Go ahead if you want to.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That does make a lot of sense right now, since it's so late.

Comment: Decided to turn my comment into a proper answer so people can vote on it

Answer (score 10):

### Move to voting phase for Best of 2019, and start Best of 2020 after 2019 is completely done

Posting as an answer so that users can vote.

Based on the comments on caird's suggestion, I think it's fine to simply go this way (it's arguably late, but it isn't *too* late yet, in the sense that we can finish this just before starting Best of 2020).

Comment: I second this idea as well.

Answer (score 4):

### Change this year's Best Of to "Best of PPCG 2019/2020"

Last year, around this time, Monica got fired, which lead to a lot of members of the PPCG community suspending their activity or leaving the site. As such, we went through a few months of low activity right when voting and bounties for the Best Of was supposed to happen, and it sort of just... didn't.

This year, the community is much more active, so I'm not too worried about the 2020 Best Of falling through in the same way. However, it would be unfair to simply ignore the brilliant contributions to the site, simply because they happened at the wrong time.

Therefore, I suggest that we open the 2020 Best Of to all posts from 2019 and 2020. The posts that were nominated for last year can be renominated, and voted on, and we usually have more offered bounties than winning posts, so we could potentially include a "2020 winner" and a "2019 winner" for some/all categories if we wanted to.

Comment: I do think it would be good to have separate winners for 2019 and 2020 because nominators and voters tend to be biased towards more recent posts.

Comment: I feel with the categories and nominations already complete it just makes the most sense to vote.  Sure it's late but I don't see that actually being much of a problem, now that nominations are already done.

Comment: How much were the 2019 nominations finished? I feel like I kind-of stopped paying attention to them with everything else that had happened. We could allow more nominations for those, though maybe it doesn't matter because nobody will remember posts from 2019 they want to nominate that haven't already been.

Comment: @xnor there's 10 categories with nominations so far, and most of them have more than one.